# Using approxfun in a package

Tags: r, package

The help for `approx` and `approxfun` includes the following warning:

> #### Warning
>
> The value returned by approxfun contains references to the code in the
>   current version of R: it is not intended to be saved and loaded into a
>   different R session. This is safer for R >= 3.0.0.

I'm not entirely sure what that means, especially the last part about being "safer for R >= 3.0.0". I've written some code that includes a function created with `approxfun`. Is it safe to now put that code into a package? I've tested it and it seems to work, but I don't know if I can rely on this or not.

This is with R 3.1.1 on Windows 7 64-bit.

The exact code is like this. I have some data on function values, and I want to approximate the underlying function (which I don't have the source code for).

```
.table <- read.table(text="x y
10.0    150
37.8    147
65.6    145
93.3    142", header=TRUE) # plus several more lines in the original 

# this function is to be exported in the package
f <- with(.table, approxfun(x, y))
```

---

EDIT: thanks to @MrFlick for pointing out that the resulting function calls `.approxfun` which is an unexported function in the stats package. So it's possible that a future version of R might omit this function, although this is probably unlikely, at least in the short term. There is another issue though. I had a closer look at the source for `approxfun`, and it ends with the following lines:

```
    ....
    x <- as.double(x)
    y <- as.double(y)
    .Call(C_ApproxTest, x, y, method, f)
    function(v) .approxfun(x, y, v, method, yleft, yright, f)
}
```

And `.approxfun` is just:

```
function (x, y, v, method, yleft, yright, f) 
.Call(C_Approx, x, y, v, method, yleft, yright, f)
```

It looks like `approxfun` calls compiled C code to initialise some data, and `.approxfun` then uses that data. If I call `approxfun` in my packaged code, can I still depend on that initial C call happening?

Comment: The `C_ApproxTest` call doeson't really matter in this case. That happens in `approxFun` which you *are* calling and all it probably does is validate input or change the data values by reference so it would effect what is enclosed in the returned function. That doesn't seem related to the issue here.

Answer (score 5):

The warning is more about if you were to use `save()` and `load()` on the function returned by `approx` fun. Using your sample data, if you look at

```
f
# function (v) 
# .approxfun(x, y, v, method, yleft, yright, f)
# <bytecode: 0x10a20d948>
# <environment: 0x10a20d0d8>
```

You can see that it's just calling a lower-level (un-exported) function with called `.approxfun`. This function isn't necessarily meant to be called directory and could change in future R versions. The values that are passed the the function are stored in the environment of the function. Observe:

```
ls.str(envir=environment(f))
# f :  num 0
# method :  int 1
# x :  num [1:4] 10 37.8 65.6 93.3
# y :  num [1:4] 150 147 145 142
# yleft :  logi NA
# yright :  logi NA
```

I'm not sure if older versions of R had a problem with storing the enclosure contents or not.

But as long as you are calling `approx()` and returning a value, you should be fine. The warning just seems to be about preserving the resulting function in an R image data file.

Comment: That's a good point about `.approxfun` not being exported. I had a closer look and there's a related issue: `approxfun` calls some compiled C code before it generates the function, and it's possible this might not happen if I put it in a package. Although everything does seem to work as intended.

Answer (score 1):

Here's an example adapted from `example(approxfun)`.

```
x <- 1:10
y <- rnorm(10)
f <- approxfun(x, y)
```

`f` is a function that approximates the `x`-`y` curve at some new points.

```
set.seed(19790801)
f(runif(10, 1, 10))
##  [1] -0.75163251 -0.75549423 -0.08916802 -0.14773144  0.55004544 -1.04215783 -0.24202646 -0.24400353 -0.16274046 -0.66116177
```

To  do this, it needs to store a copy of `x` and `y` somewhere.  You can see them using:

```
environment(f)$x
## [1]  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9 10
environment(f)$y
## [1] -0.2841479  1.0499758 -0.2363440  0.0399924 -0.2607020  0.5553470 -1.5858871 -0.8552268  0.2645726 -1.1651585
```

So does this work if you save `f` and load it into a different session?

```
saveRDS(f, "f.rds")

# Start a new R session now
f <- readRDS("f.rds")
```

Do we get the same answer in the new session when calling `f`, even if `x` and `y` are defined differently?

```
x <- 99:90
y <- rlnorm(10)
set.seed(19790801)
f(runif(10, 1, 10))
##  [1] -0.75163251 -0.75549423 -0.08916802 -0.14773144  0.55004544 -1.04215783 -0.24202646 -0.24400353 -0.16274046 -0.66116177
```

Yes!  So it seems safe, at least in this case.

---

As MrFlick pointed out, the warning is due to `f` calling `stats:::.approxfun`, which isn't exported, and therefore could potentially change in future versions of R.

So you are safe copying `f` between sessions using the same version of R, but not copying it to sessions in potential future versions of R.  That is, I'm translating the warning as

> Do not use the results of `approxfun` as a form of permanent data storage.